# How to ensure a middleware is not wrapped twice?

Tags: clojure, middleware, ring

How do you ensure a middleware is not applied twice?

My application is using `bidi` and I have my routes and handlers separate. So my final ring handler has some middlewares (such as `wrap-params` and `wrap-session`) and some of my handlers have their own custom middlewares. I can manually watch over my main handler's constructor and my handlers file, but I would rather not rely on manual vigilance.

Is there a design that helps manage middlewares better? Or some library?

My structure looks like this:

```
1. routes                                 2. handlers
      \                                      /
       \                                    /
    3. (bidi.ring/make-handler routes handlers)
```

It's possible to wrap something in `2` and then again in `3`.

`3` is actually a [component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component) and `make-handler` is called in its `start`. `handler` & `routes` come from `3`'s component's dependencies. I have considered adding another protocol to `1` & `2` with a `wrap-middlewares` method, but the order of middlewares is significant. For example (buddy-auth's) `wrap-authentication` depends on `wrap-session` & `wrap-params`.

Answer (score 1):

for middleware you control it's fairly straightforward, you can just have each middleware **add a key with it's name to the request** and bail (or noop if you're feeling lenient) if that key is in any request it recieves. for middleware you don't control i suppose were stuck with staring at the code and thinking really hard, or as you describe it "manual vigilance".